# Display dashboard other than admin user

Tags: plugins

I just wonder if there is a way to display dashboard for other than admin user(it should be) but for some reason nothing displaying except my account page.

I created a new user role staff using user role editor plugin and added a new user set to staff using basic capabilities adding post, reading private pages etc. However, when I login nothing displays other than Myaccount page

Answer (score 0):

You must assign admin capability to custom role.

You can assign 'manage_options' capability for user role plugin.

OR

Add following code in custom plugin or functions.php file of child theme, and reactive plugin/theme after code is added.

```
$result = add_role(
    'staff',
    __( 'Staff' ),
    array(
        'manage_options' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried ure_manage_options for some reason nothing changed, I wonder it should be easy to add a new post other than admin that's what I am trying  by creating a new role for it. All I want is based on user login dashboard changes to their capabilities

Comment: Try deactivate and then activating the user role plugin

Comment: it ain't work either and the plugin is Members

Comment: Then try adding above code in child theme's functions.php file or create new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin you can give any access to any user. please review [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

Hope this plugin works for you.